# In classical guitar fingering notation, what does "-4" mean?

Tags: guitar, notation, classical-guitar

In this classical guitar piece, a note is given a finger marking of **-4**:

[image: sheet music]

To play this passage, am I correct in assuming you would:

1. Play the first note of the passage (B) with your third finger.
2. Play the note marked **4** (C#) with your pinky.
3. Move your hand down and play the note marked **-4** (B) with your pinky again?

If that's the case, why bother marking the note with **-4**? Why not just mark it as **4**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dash signifies a **guide**. The L.H. fourth finger (pinky) moves down from the 9th fret C# to the 7th fret B. Although it might seem obvious that both notes are with the fourth finger, when sight-reading the dash makes quite a lot of difference; just that one extra bit of information helps you to know that you are playing both notes with the same finger, but moving that finger along the string.

Comment: Not seen that before. Almost seems like it could be played as a slide down, although there's no slur; as it's fairly quick. Nice to see you back answering.

Comment: It would have been more clear in the notation if it was represented more like "4--4" instead of "4 -4"

Comment: Maybe, but it's a commonly used convention as it's written, and as I say, once you're used to it, it makes reading a lot easier.